# Concurrency: Multiplying Matrices. Can someone please elaborate on concurrent.multi and why it isn't working in my code

Tags: java, matrix, concurrency

**Hello, thank you for caring.**

my assignment goes as follows: **Write a Java program that can calculate the result of a single array of 10 integers by a second single
array of 10 integers concurrently.*

**I'm having trouble understanding the multi object from the import -
concurrent.multi.Mult;**
if someone could please break it down a little and why i am getting the error message im getting.

**im getting the error: "No enclosing instance of type multi is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type multi (e.g. x.new A() where x is an instance of multi)."**

here is my code.

```
package concurrent;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

import concurrent.multi.Mult;

public class matrix {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int[] a = {4, 4, 5, 1, 8, 10, 15, 1, 6, 8 };
            int[] b = {2, 7, 5, 4, 8, 12, 13, 1, 7, 8 };

            // multiply these two matricies
            //int result = a[0]*b[0] + a[1][b]; // up to a[9]*b[9]
            int result = 0;
            for (int i=0; i<a.length; i++)
                result = result + a[i]*b[i];
            System.out.printf("Result %d%n", result);

            // create 10 Mult objects to run as threads
            Mult m1 = new Mult(a[0],b[0]); //where error occurs
            Mult m2 = new Mult(a[1],b[1]);
            Mult m3 = new Mult(a[2],b[2]);
            Mult m4 = new Mult(a[3],b[3]);
            Mult m5 = new Mult(a[4],b[4]);
            Mult m6 = new Mult(a[5],b[5]);
            Mult m7 = new Mult(a[6],b[6]);
            Mult m8 = new Mult(a[7],b[7]);
            Mult m9 = new Mult(a[8],b[8]);
            Mult m10 = new Mult(a[9],b[9]);
            // you do the rest here

            // creates a thread pool
            ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

            executorService.execute(m1);
            executorService.execute(m2);
            executorService.execute(m3);
            executorService.execute(m4);
            executorService.execute(m5);
            executorService.execute(m6);
            executorService.execute(m7);
            executorService.execute(m8);
            executorService.execute(m9);
            executorService.execute(m10);
            // you do the rest here

            // when threads finish we have all the results
            // now add them together to produce the final answer
            result = m1.getResult() + m2.getResult(); // + you do the rest

            executorService.shutdown();

        }
    }
```

Comment: I am sorry but I can not find any documentation for `concurrent.multi.Mult`, If that is a private library and you do not show the code we can not help you understand the error.

Comment: it was recommended by eclipse to import it with the first mult instantiation.

Comment: That only means that you have that dependency in your classpath. If you google for `concurrent.multi.Mult` I can not find anything related. Not even an API documentation. How can you use a class if you do not know where it comes. How do you know what `Mult` is supposed to do?

Comment: my teacher left partial code for us to edit and it was in there i was hoping someone on here would elaborate that's why i was unsure. thank you for helping